# Nearest neighbor matching in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given two DataFrames (t1, t2), both with a column 'x', how would I append a column to t1 with the ID of t2 whose 'x' value is the nearest to the 'x' value in t1?

```
t1:
id  x
1   1.49
2   2.35

t2:
id  x
3   2.36
4   1.5

output:
id  id2
1   4
2   3
```

I can do this by creating a new DataFrame and iterating on t1.groupby() and doing look ups on t2 then merging, but this take incredibly long given a 17 million row t1 DataFrame.

Is there a better way to accomplish? I've scoured the pandas docs regarding groupby, apply, transform, agg, etc. But an elegant solution has yet to present itself despite my thought that this would be a common problem.

Comment: Do the dataframes always have the same shape? eg same amount of columns and rows?

Answer (score 5):

Using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('x'),
                   df2.sort_values('x'),
                   on='x', 
                   direction='nearest', 
                   suffixes=['', '_2'])

print(df)
Out[975]: 
   id     x  id_2
0   3  0.87     6
1   1  1.49     5
2   2  2.35     4
```

---

Method 2 `reindex`

```
df1['id2']=df2.set_index('x').reindex(df1.x,method='nearest').values
df1
   id     x  id2
0   1  1.49    4
1   2  2.35    3
```

Answer (score 1):

convert to list t1 and t2 and sort them after this 
and with the zip() function match the id

```
list1 = t1.values.tolist()
list2 = t2.values.tolist()

list1.sort() // ASC ORD DESC YOU DECIDE 
list2.sort()

list3 = zip(list1,list2)

print(list3)
```

//after that you must see the output like (1,4),(2,3)

Answer (score 1):

*Alternatively, you can use* `round` *to* `1` *precision*

```
t1 = {'id': [1, 2], 'x': [1.49,2.35]}
t2 = {'id': [3, 4], 'x': [2.36,1.5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(t1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(t2)
df  = df1.round(1).merge(df2.round(1), on='x', suffixes=('','2')).drop('x',1)
print(df)
      id   id2
0     1    4
1     2    3
```

- *add* `.drop('x',1)` *to remove the output for the binding column 'x'.*
- *add* `suffixes=('','2')` *to rename the column titles.*

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate a new array with the distance from each element in `t1` to each element in `t2`, and then take the `argmin` along the rows to get the right index. This has the advantage that you can choose whatever distance function you like, and it does not require the dataframes to be of equal length. 
It creates one intermediate array of size len(t1) * len(t2). Using a pandas builtin might be more memory-efficient, but this should be as fast as you can get as everything is done on the C side of numpy. You could always do this method in batches if memory is a problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2], "x": np.array([1.49, 2.35])})
t2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [3, 4], "x": np.array([2.36, 1.5])})
```

Now comes the part doing the actual work. The `.to_numpy()` bit is important since otherwise Pandas tries to merge on the indices. The first line uses broadcasting to create horizontal and vertical "repetitions" in a memory-efficient way.

```
dist = np.abs(t1["x"][np.newaxis, :] - t2["x"][:, np.newaxis])
closest_idx = np.argmin(dist, axis=1)
closest_id = t2["id"][closest_idx].to_numpy()

output = pd.DataFrame({"id1": t1["id"], "id2": closest_id})
print(output)
```