# Complicated Approximate Match VLOOKUP Equivalent in Python

Tags: python, vlookup, approximate

I have two csv files that look something like this:

csv1:

```
ID     From_Depth   To_Depth
ABC    314          315
ABC    315          316
ABC    316          317
ABC    317          318
ABC    319          320
ABC    320          321
ABC    321          322
ABC    322          323
ABC    323          324
```

csv2:

```
ID     Position     Label
ABC    314.366      68
ABC    315.476      68
ABC    315.964      68
ABC    316.321      69
ABC    317.953      69
ABC    318.246      69
ABC    318.75       70
ABC    319.341      70
ABC    320.054      71
ABC    320.826      71
ABC    321.562      71
ABC    322.206      72
ABC    322.953      72
ABC    323.058      72
```

What I want to do is create an additional column in csv1 called 'Label' that contains the label of the Position (in csv2) closest to the mean of the From_Depth and To_Depth (in csv1).

The output csv would look like this:

```
ID     From_Depth   To_Depth    Label
ABC    314          315         68
ABC    315          316         68
ABC    316          317         69
ABC    317          318         69
ABC    319          320         70
ABC    320          321         71
ABC    321          322         71
ABC    322          323         72
ABC    323          324         72
```

In excel, I can use VLOOKUP to accomplish this (assuming the two csvs are side by side in excel):

> =VLOOKUP((C2+B2)/2,$E$2:$F$15,2,TRUE)

I want to know how to accomplish the same thing in python. It seems to me that the VLOOKUP *'equivalents'* such as `merge` or `insert` with `map` are not able to handle a more complicated task such as the one I've got.

Comment: Are you using `pandas` for this or you want to solve it with standard library?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have csv1 in df1 and csv2 in df2

you may create a new column in df1 with the formula applicable and then merge on that -

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')

df1['avg_depth'] = (df1['From_Depth'] + df1['To_Depth'])/2
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='avg_depth', right_on='Position', how='left')
df_merged = df_merged[['ID', 'From_Depth', 'To_Depth', 'Label']]

df_merged.to_csv('output_csv.csv', index=None)
```

What I could understand from your lookup formula - avg depths in csv1 are looked up with position column in csv2, if found it takes the F column (Label).

Edit:
As  Matthias mentioned pd.merge_asof gets the nearest values on the join key. One can also use this

```
df_merged = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('avg_depth'), df2.sort_values('Position'), left_on='avg_depth', right_on='Position', direction='nearest', suffixes=['', '_2'])
```

Comment: This only works if the average depth happens to be in csv2. In most cases it won't be, and you need to find the closest match in csv2 (try with the example data). You could probably update this pretty easily using merge_asof, as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55754579/3830997.

Comment: I suppose you're right, thanks for the insight, would love to learn more