# comparing values among all other values in that variable to locate nearest neighbor in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent of the following code in Pandas to find the nearest neighbor by comparing every observation to every other observation, but in Pandas, I don't want to do this with a for loop, since with large datasets, it would seem to be work in vectors vs loops.

Below, let's say that the cholesterol values are the final squared distances based off of other variables. How would I compute the euclidean distance of each cholesterol value to every other value in that variable (so the sum of (xi - yi)^2 and then find the minimum (euclidean) distance, such that it would return its nearest neighbor (whether or not the closest person has in the fifth column and then in the sixth column--whether or not that person has heart disease. So for instance, the nearest neighbor of Braund should be Allen, since (7.25 - 8.05)^2 + (9.45 - 9.23)^2 ... is the closest value.

The answer to this question: [Nearest neighbor matching in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754477/nearest-neighbor-matching-in-pandas) is close, but deals with merging data frames and not the values within vectors of one data frame.

```
d = {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
     'cholesterol_1': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05], 'cholesterol_2': [9.45, 28.23, 1, 9.23], 'cholesterol_3': [8, 37.83, 1 , 9.35],
    'heart_disease': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'],}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Okay, just added. Hopefully that is clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `scipy` (to calculate the Euclidean distances) and `numpy` to do computation on the resulting symmetric matrix:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
arr = df.filter(like='cholesterol')
euclidean_dist = cdist(arr, arr, metric='euclidean')
np.fill_diagonal(euclidean_dist, np.inf)
df['nearest_neighbor'] = df.loc[euclidean_dist.argmin(axis=1), 'name'].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
           cholesterol_1  cholesterol_2  cholesterol_3 heart_disease  nearest_neighbor  
name                                                                   
Braund              7.25           9.45           8.00             Y             Allen  
Cummings           71.83          28.23          37.83             Y             Allen  
Heikkinen           0.00           1.00           1.00             N            Braund  
Allen               8.05           9.23           9.35             Y            Braund
```

Comment: Okay, thank you...is there no way to do this solely in pandas?

Comment: @James It's possible but we'll have to calculate the distances manually. Do you not have scipy or numpy?

Comment: I do, but I was trying to figure out a solution in Pandas to gain a better understanding of how to do that (or similar) kinds of operations...using something like df.assign(new_column = ...)

Comment: @James If you’re willing to use numpy, it could be done in a vectorized way. If you only want to use pandas however, it looks like you’ll need to either repeat rows along to columns or use a loop. Either way, it’s going to be a bit ugly. Certainly can’t be achieved by assigning a few columns.

Comment: Thanks...so in thinking this over, I think on the one hand there is a desire to gain a deeper understanding of pandas. Since I work predominantly in R, Pandas is naturally easiest for me and seems more efficient (using apply, etc.) than for loops. But perhaps there's no way of getting around a deeper understanding of Numpy. In the larger scheme of things, the best thing seems to be to work predominantly in Pandas while incorporating useful functions. What are your thoughts? But it seems like every time, I want to use Numpy, the dataset needs to be converted to an array.

Comment: @James pandas has columns, so if they don’t match, you get NaNs. Numpy doesn’t have those, so you can do broadcasting in a more general way. In this specific case, since you want the difference between cholesterol levels between everyone, column names don’t match, so pandas can’t do it. But numpy is worth learning imo; its advanced indexing is very useful for example. There are a lot of equivalent methods in both libraries so it’s easier to learn one if you understand the other.